# What paradoxes arise from quantifying over EVERYTHING?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, philosophy-of-logic

This question is in context of the umbrella view of objects, that there exists a general category that everything falls under. Here are the quote and link that peaked my curiosity.

> Finally, note that there may be reason to be wary of any fully general category (whether expressed by ‘object’, ‘thing’, ‘entity’, or whatnot.). There may be reason, that is, to doubt the metaphysical conjunct of the Umbrella View. First and perhaps most importantly, there are paradoxes and puzzles associated with talking about. or ‘quantifying over’, literally every thing.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/object

Comment: Are you including mathematical objects? If you use the [von Neumann definition of ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) where each ordinal is defined as the set of all smaller ordinals (the smallest one being the empty set), then you can't have a set of all ordinals since that would itself be a new ordinal larger than any of its members (apparently this is a specific version of the more general [Burali-Forti paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox))

Comment: [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#Russell's_paradox) , [Berry paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox), the key problem is expressed in the [vicious circle principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicious_circle_principle). Look at [Williamson's Everything](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1520-8583.2003.00017.x) for trying to deal with that.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "each ordinal is defined as the set of all smaller ordinals" -- You just quantified over the class of all ordinals. You made a statement about every ordinal. Yes?

Comment: It's true that quantifying over a group in logical terms is not quite the same as treating them as a set mathematically, the problem with the ordinals only arises if you try to do the latter. Not sure if there are any basic paradoxes with quantifying over everything in the logical sense alone.

Comment: @Conifold I don't see how either Russell's or Berry's paradoxes are paradoxes of quantification. Russell shows that full **comprehension** isn't permissible, but says nothing about full **quantification** (although of course you can argue that the particular issue with the Russell set is that it's defined using full quantification, that's not necessary). Berry meanwhile has nothing to do with quantification at all that I can see, but rather the issue of defining definability. Since this is adequately treated in first-order logic, which does allow full quantification, I don't see the relevance.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I took that quote to be referring to EVERYTHING, including abstract, mathematical objects.

Comment: @NoahSchweber On my reading, the OP is not about "quantifying" specifically, the quote uses it next to "talking about". And one of the problems is that "general category that everything falls under" is viciously mutable, as those paradoxes show.

Comment: @Conifold when Russel says “all propositions are either true or false", is the statement itself a contradiction, or is the problem that it can lead to contradictions if you suppose that the sentence itself is contained in the set of things it is referring to?

Comment: Contradictions are only a symptom, avoiding them does not guarantee that the arguments are valid. The root problem is the potential equivocation on "everything". One can track its scope directly to keep it fixed in the course of an argument, although it is not so straightforward, especially when quantification is involved. There are technical devices, like hierarchy of types or restricted comprehension, to do so systematically. But the end result is that "everything" so handled isn't really everything, but some restricted class. Arguments for a variety of them just have the same template.

Comment: @Conifold So it's hard to keep track of what "everything" is because when you say "everything" without giving a clear scope, you create another "thing" that is included in "everything," right?

Comment: Yes, essentially. This is what Russell's vicious circle principle was meant to preclude. But it is more pernicious than it seems, because when we quantify over "everything" it is not even clear how to control scope if we want to count in some potential "new creations". Type stratification would do it, but it creates a whole hierarchy of "everythings" and more, which is rather unwieldy. Mathematicians after Zermelo chose to restrict comprehension extensionally instead, which allows some breaking of the principle. In the definition of the least upper bound, most famously.